# Lumen throws 405 error even though method is allowed

Tags: php, lumen, http-status-code-405

I'm implementing an API using the Lumen framework, and am having a hard time with one pesky route. All my other routes work perfectly, but this one route keeps throwing a 405 error even though the used method is allowed. The worst part is that it doesn't always throw this error, but it does for 90% of my requests.

The simplified route definition (It's actually nested in a few groups, which you can see below) is:

```
$router->post('v1/monitoring/executions/{execution_id}/calls/{call_id}/events', 'EventController@createEvent');
```

However, whenever I post something, I get hit with a `405 Method not Allowed` exception. Checking the Apache logs does display that a POST request was received:

> [08/Nov/2017:08:05:32 +0000] "POST /v1/monitoring/executions/1/calls/1/events HTTP/1.1" 405 49 "-" "PostmanRuntime/6.4.1"

The full path to this route in my routing file is:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () use ($router) {

    $router->group(['prefix' => 'monitoring/executions', 'namespace' => 'Monitoring', 'middleware' => 'integration_token'], function () use ($router) {
        // POST and PUT requests for executions

        $router->group(['prefix' => '{execution_id}/calls'], function () use ($router) {
            // POST and PUT routes for calls

            $router->group(['prefix' => '{call_id}/events'], function () use ($router) {
                $router->post('/', 'EventController@createEvent');
                $router->put('{event_id}', 'Eventcontroller@updateEvent');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The `integration_token` middleware doesn't return any 405 errors either:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = $request->headers->all();

        if (!isset($headers['x-integration-token'])) {
            abort(400, "X-Integration-Token header is required");
        }

        $token = $headers['x-integration-token'][0];

        $pattern = '/^[A-Za-z0-9]{32}$/';
        $pattern_matches = preg_match($pattern, $token);

        if (!$pattern_matches) {
            abort(400, "Malformed X-Integration-Token header");
        }

        try {
            $integration = Integration::where(['access_token' => $token])->firstOrFail();
            $integration_id = $integration->id;
            $request->attributes->set('integration_id', $integration_id);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            abort(403, "Incorrect access token: $token");
        }


        return $next($request);
    }
```

Neither does the controller:

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Monitoring;

```
use App\Call;
use App\Event;
use App\Execution;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Libraries\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function createEvent(Request $request, $execution_id, $call_id) {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['execution_id'] = $execution_id;
        $input['call_id'] = $call_id;
        $input['time_string'] = Helpers::getTimestampTz();
        $input['time'] = Helpers::getMicroTime();

        Helpers::validateRequiredFields(Event::class, $input);

        // Verify execution and call exist
        Execution::findOrFail($execution_id);
        Call::findOrFail($call_id);

        $event = Event::create($input);

        return response()->json($event)->setStatusCode(201);
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

I honestly have no idea what might be causing this issue, but it's driving me crazy! Any help in fixing this issue would be very much appreciated.

Comment: you forgot the most important piece of code , the controller function

Comment: @madalinivascu Whoops, thanks for pointing that out! I added it to the question.

Comment: if you remove all the content from the controller do you receive a blank page?findOrFail will throw a exception if item is not found

Comment: Removing the content from my controller function does indeed return a blank page (status 200). However, I am 100% sure that the Execution and Call object exist. I use postman to first create an execution, save the ID in a variable, then create a call and save that ID in another variable, and pass those variables into the url.

Comment: Manually querying and counting seems to work: `$execution_count = Execution::where('id', $execution_id)->count();`. I now check if the count is 1, and if it isn't I call `abort()`